# php mysqli sum based on a column data associated with user session

Tags: php, mysql

Morning

I'm trying to write a php mysqli sum query based on querying mysql db column data associated with user session. So the script should go off get all the db data associated with the session username in column A, then extract a variable out of column B, then sum the column C values that match the Column B variable.

Heres what I have and it produces 0 as a result, not a sum of the data in the column C for Sales.

DB table looks like:

```
Column A / Column B / Column C

Bill     / Sales    / 15.00

Helen    / Sales    / 32.00

James    / Accounts / 20.00

..
```

Current code looks like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $db = new mysqli('DBHOST.com', 'DBUsername', 'DBPassword', 'DBNAME');
    if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE ColumnA = '" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if ($count == 1) {
        $output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $columnBresult = trim($output['ColumnB']);
    }
    $sumquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(ColumnC) as total FROM Table_Name WHERE ColumnB = '$columnBresult'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sumquery);
    $sum = $row['total'];
    echo $sum > 0 || $sum !== null ? $sum : "0";
?>
```

Any ideas welcomed..

Comment: The code looks fine, just check is there any username assigned in your session variable. What `print_r($_SESSION)` tells you after `session_start()`?

Comment: Session start has the username in carried over from the DB login on another page, it's the right value and exists in the DB. I have it further up the page in a bit of script not shown here where I greet the user.

Comment: Just to be clear I am trying to get the department total of column C, based on Bills associated department name in column B.

Comment: So what do you have if you add `echo $_SESSION['username']` just before db call?

Comment: I get the username.

Answer (score 1):

On top of all check is there any username value in your `$_SESSION['username']` variable. In addition you can achieve such calculation with single query by joining the same table:

DB table:

```
mysql> select * from table_name;
+---------+----------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB  | ColumnC |
+---------+----------+---------+
| Bill    | Sales    |      15 |
| Helen   | Sales    |      32 |
| James   | Accounts |      20 |
+---------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(t1.ColumnC) AS total
FROM
    table_name t1
    INNER JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB
WHERE
    t2.ColumnA = 'Bill'
```

Result:

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
| 47.00 |
+-------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: So my PHP should look like    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(t1.ColumnC) as total FROM t1 INNER JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB WHERE t2.ColumnA = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'")

Comment: In general - yes. But again, check what do you have in this session variable and ensure that the username exists there.

Comment: Ok echo of username is fine it's being returned but my code above is NOT pulling all of the department costs back I'm getting a portion but not all. Just trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
 <?php 

 session_start();

 $db = new mysqli('DBHost.com', 'DBUsername', 'DBPassword', 'DBName');
 if($db->connect_errno > 0){
 die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
 }

 $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ColumnB FROM Table_Name WHERE ColumnA = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'");
 $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
 $dept = $fetch['ColumnB'];


 $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(ColumnC) AS total FROM Table_Name WHERE ColumnB = '$dept'");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $sum = $row['total'];

 echo $sum > 0 || $sum!==null ? $sum : "0"; 
 ?>
```

This worked for me.